# How do I solve this md5 algorithm?

Tags: php, md5

I'm trying to solve, how is created the email verification code which sent by site to new users.

I'm very investigated of this script library and find this line.

```
 <a href="{{ route('auth.email.verify', [ 'token' => data_get($user, 'verify_token.token').md5($user->email) ]) }}">
```

So,my opinion is verify token + email = verify code.But i didn't get the code by this way.

This is the token code saved on db verify_token table

```
9bd4e22f70b2cbe99245c71a3502b504a8713951
```

This is the code which send to user's email.So user see this code

```
example.com/verify?token=1c428d4dc20602f439142feab8f572022c5d960feeceabaae007439eb87933f0846ee30e
```

So I solve that `eeceabaae007439eb87933f0846ee30e` equivalent in email is `batista@gmail.com`

But i can't figure out what crypted by script before the `eeceabaae007439eb87933f0846ee30e`

Comment: _First off_ MD5 is a HASH not encrytion

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to achieve here. Are you trying to UN-HASH these 2 tokens ?

Comment: the type of the preceding hash is sha1, but your stored value is not the same hash so the .token part is most likely salting the hash you have stored with something

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm trying to un-hash 1c428d4dc20602f439142feab8f572022c5d960f

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to UN-HASH a HASH. Thats the point. Its supposed to be a one way process

Comment: I need a which parameter hashed by algorithm then. The last part of hash is e-mail but 1c428d4dc20602f439142feab8f572022c5d960f is still unknown.

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to achieve. I have a feeling this is a simple verify your email process, if I am right all you need to do is generate a token (anyhow) save it with the newly registered user. When they validate by clicking, you check that the token exists on the DB and Bob's yer fathers brother

Comment: Okay i figure out finally. The first part of hash random key (one way) as you mentioned.So random key+md5 email is email verification code.Thank you for idea.